# How to fix fix broken install command (due to zoom installation)

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, zoom-meeting

Installing zoom-meeting created a broken package. Since then I've tried everything, but nothing can be done.

[image: Package Manager screenshot]

When I enter the command `sudo apt-get --purge remove zoom` I get these results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Build dependency tree... Done
Read status information... Done      
The following package has been installed automatically and is no longer required:
  libwmf0.2-7
Please use "sudo apt autoremove" to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic zoom*
0 updated, 0 newly installed, 2 to be removed and 26 not updated.
3 partially installed or removed.
After this operation, 698 MB of disk space will be freed.
Would you like to continue? [Y/n] o
(Reading the database... 533735 files and directories already installed)
Remove linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 3: /etc/default/grub: For: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic package processing error (--remove) :
 the installed linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic script post-removal package sub-process returned an output status of error 1
dpkg: too many errors, shutdown
Errors were encountered during execution :
 linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic
Execution was stopped because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Entering the command : `sudo apt autoremove`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Build dependency tree... Done
Read status information... Done      
You can run "apt --fix-broken install" to correct these problems.
The following packages contain unmet dependencies:
 zoom: Dependency: libxcb-xtest0 but it is not installed
        Depends on: libxcb-cursor0 but it is not installed
        Recommends: libegl1-mesa but it is not installed
        Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installed
E: Dependencies not met. Try "apt --fix-broken install" without package
   (or specify a solution).
```

When I enter the command `sudo apt --fix-broken-install`

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Build dependency tree... Done
Read status information... Done      
Correct dependencies... Done
The following package has been installed automatically and is no longer required:
  libwmf0.2-7
Please use "sudo apt autoremove" to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed: 
  libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-xtest0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-xtest0
0 updated, 2 newly installed, 1 to be removed and 26 not updated.
3 partially installed or removed.
It is necessary to take 0 o/15.4 kB from the archives.
After this operation, 14.2 MB of disk space will be freed up.
Do you wish to continue? [Y/n] o
(Reading the database... 533735 files and directories already installed)
Remove linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 3: /etc/default/grub: For: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic package processing error (--remove) :
 the installed linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic script post-removal package subprocess returned an error output status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stop
Errors were encountered during execution :
 linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic
Execution was stopped because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I'd probably try `sudo aptitude` first, it's a ncurses frontend to apt. But `sudo dpkg purge zoom`, followed by `sudo apt -f install` might clear it; you may need to append `--force-depends` to the dpkg call to make it ignore dependencies. Careful, you can end up with a non-bootablev system if you remove required packages.

Comment: It looks like the first thing you need to do is fix the `/etc/default/grub` file - most likely it is something simple like a comment (`# For full documentation of the options ...`) having been uncommented

Comment: ... see for example [/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: If: not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192919/usr-sbin-grub-mkconfig-1-etc-default-grub-if-not-found)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @pbhj it worked ty but it was `sudo dpkg  **--purge** zoom` not `sudo dpkg purge zoom`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dpkg  **--purge** zoom`
Solved the problem after making `sudo apt update` `sudo apt upgrade`